# response.Addheader not working anymore

Tags: iis-7, vbscript, asp-classic

i have a page for 404 error and the response.status is 404
yesterday the response.Addheader was working fine but today it is just showing a blank page and if i check the header status it is 404.

here is part of my code

```
Response.Status="404 Not Found"
Response.AddHeader "Location", domain & "/page-not-found"
```

in the same code - the 301 status works fine

IIS 7, vb script, classic asp

Comment: Location headers runs only Status code equal 3XX etc and it's client related. Maybe it was due to cache.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit your web.config to redirect to there on 404...

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <customErrors defaultRedirect="/page-not-found"
                    mode="RemoteOnly">
         <error statusCode="404"
                redirect="/page-not-found"/>
      </customErrors>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Source:[Web.config custom errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)